# unix all if statements in one place

Tags: bash

I am newly learning shell script ! i tried following code but i have error

> line 15: syntax error near unexpected token `elif

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Enter the number : " n

if [ $n -eq 1 ]
then
    echo "$n is equal to 1 true"

    elif [ $n -lt 4 ]
    then
        echo "$n is less than value of 4 ture"
    else
        echo "$n is not less then value of 4 false"

    elif [ $n -gt 10 ]
    then
        echo "$n is greater than the value of 10 true"
    else
        echo "$n is not greater than the value of 10 false"

    if [ $n -ge 0 ]
    then
        echo "$n is greater than or equal to 0"
    else
        echo "$n is not greater than or equal to 0"
    fi
else
    "Bye"
fi
```

Can anyone help ?

Comment: `if`/`else` or `if`/`elif`/`else` or `if/`elif`/`elif`.../`else` but not `if`/`elif`/`else`/`elif`/`else`.

Comment: Pasting the code in http://www.shellcheck.net/ reveals you are missing some `fi`s.

Comment: Hay fedorqui thanks for your shellcheck link

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hard to tell what your intention is. The correct answer depends on what you want to do here. My guess is that you want this:

```
if [ $n -eq 1 ]
then
    echo "$n is equal to 1 true"

elif [ $n -lt 4 ]
then
    echo "$n is less than value of 4 true"

elif [ $n -gt 10 ]
then
    echo "$n is greater than the value of 10 true"

elif [ $n -ge 0 ]
then
    # This will be true if $n is >= 4 and <= 10 
    echo "$n is greater than or equal to 0"
else
    # Negative
    "Bye"
fi
```